# Random Forest and Logistic Regression showing accuracy of 99%

Tags: python, random-forest, logistic-regression, outliers, regularized

I have 50000 observations with 70% positive and 30% negative target variable
I'm getting accuracy of around 96-99% which seems unreal of course and I'm worried that my model is over-fitting which I don't understand why. I replaced all outliers with 5th and 95th quantile. Standardized the data yet it is showing this unreal accuracy. 
A bit of online search and people suggested to check for the difference between training and test data accuracy, which i did and for Random Forest it came

```
Training Accuracy: 0.997975
Test Accuracy: 0.9715
```

For logistic regression it shows

```
Training Accuracy: 0.967225
Test Accuracy: 0.9647
```

This is the code I used for running the model:

```
clf = LogisticRegression()
trained_model = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
trained_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = trained_model.predict(X_test)      

accuracy_score(y_train, trained_model.predict(X_train))
accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
```

I also tried kfold cross validation which gave similar results

```
skfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=100)
model_skfold = LogisticRegression()
results_skfold = model_selection.cross_val_score(model_skfold, X, Y, cv=skfold)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (results_skfold.mean()*100.0))
```

Lastly I applied regularization technique to check for results and this is the result  I got

```
for c in C:
    clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', C=c, solver='liblinear')
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred_log_reg = clf.predict(X_test)
    acc_log_reg = round( clf.score(X_train, y_train) * 100, 2)
    print (str(acc_log_reg) + ' percent')
    print('C:', c)
    print('Coefficient of each feature:', clf.coef_)
    print('Training accuracy:', clf.score(X_train_std, y_train))
    print('Test accuracy:', clf.score(X_test_std, y_test))
    print('')
```

The results

```
96.72 percent
C: 10
Coefficient of each feature: [[-2.50e+00 -1.40e-03  2.65e+00  4.09e-02 -2.03e-03  2.75e-04  1.79e-02
  -2.13e-03 -2.18e-03  2.90e-03  2.69e-03 -4.93e+00 -4.89e+00 -4.88e+00
  -3.27e+00 -3.30e+00]]
Training accuracy: 0.5062
Test accuracy: 0.5027

96.72 percent
C: 1
Coefficient of each feature: [[-2.50e+00 -1.41e-03  2.66e+00  4.10e-02 -2.04e-03  2.39e-04  1.68e-02
  -3.29e-03 -3.80e-03  2.52e-03  2.62e-03 -4.22e-02 -9.55e-03  0.00e+00
  -1.73e+00 -1.77e+00]]
Training accuracy: 0.482525
Test accuracy: 0.4738

96.74 percent
C: 0.1
Coefficient of each feature: [[-2.46e+00 -1.38e-03  2.58e+00  4.03e-02 -1.99e-03  2.22e-04  1.44e-02
  -4.49e-03 -5.13e-03  2.03e-03  2.20e-03  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
   0.00e+00 -6.54e-03]]
Training accuracy: 0.616675
Test accuracy: 0.6171

95.92 percent
C: 0.001
Coefficient of each feature: [[-1.43e+00 -6.82e-04  1.19e+00  2.73e-02 -1.10e-03  1.22e-04  0.00e+00
  -2.74e-03 -2.55e-03  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
   0.00e+00  0.00e+00]]
Training accuracy: 0.655075
Test accuracy: 0.6565
```

The codes I used for Standardization and replace outliers

```
std_scale = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train_std = std_scale.transform(X_train)
X_test_std  = std_scale.transform(X_test)

X.clip(lower=X.quantile(0.05), upper=X.quantile(0.95), axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Do let me know if any other information is required and any guidance will be appreciated

EDIT:

HEATMAP
[image]

Comment: Could it be that your data is simply easy to classify ?  99% on train set and 96% on test looks like a reasonable overfit imho.

Comment: Your coefficients are all very close to 0, except for the third feature. It could be that the third feature is a very good predictor of the output. Try a model with just the third feature and see if it gives similar results

Comment: I thought about it as well, it's actually given to me by a company for junior data scientist position and I doubt they would give something this easy even for junior position. Do you think there is a chance of class imbalance? But i read that 70-30 with this much data is fine. Or it might be multicolinearity issue although VIF shows none of the variable has a value of VIF greater than 1.6

Comment: @hyeri Can you do correlation between each feature and the output?

Comment: @mattyx17 I have edited the original post and added a heatmap hope it will help

Comment: btw I excluded age, price as they seemed to be correlating the most and accuracy dropped to 70% but I guess that's explainable since they were correlating the most so when I excluded them the accuracy dropped

Comment: Hmm yeah it definitely looks like age and price are your most significant while all the other explanatory variables are really insignificant. I would say your best bet is to use some combination of backward elimination / forward selection. I think you'll likely arrive at a model of age + price to model sales, possibly with one other explanatory variable